# Mame, KxMame, GMameUI not working after upgrade

Tags: 10.10

In previous releases, Mame and KxMame were working fine, but not any more since 10.10 .

Both front ends ask for the executable path, but no matter which I choose, they don't work.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Jorge this is not an upgrade problem. I had it installing gmame from scratch on Maverick.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this solution](http://www.ubuntu-es.org/node/142974) .

The site is in Spanish but I've translated it:

1. Uninstall package `xmame-sld` with Synaptic .
2. Install two packages from this [page](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/x/xmame/):

   - Install:
     `xmame-sdl_0.106-2.1_i386.deb   21-Jun-2.008 21:02 9.4M`
   - Then upgrade with this one:
     `xmame-sdl_0.106-3.2_i386.deb 06-Dec-2009 11:55 9.4M`

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after installing gmame. I manually installed the mame[image: Download mame] package and everything started working again.

```
sudo apt-get install mame
```

Looks like it is a packaging problem, maybe a missing dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this solution on many pages, though it doesn't repair the Kxmame bug: just install another mame program.

Answer (score 0):

Could not get xmame to work in Ubuntu 11.04 Natty AMD64 with GmameUI so I installed mame and it all worked.

Comment: @pr1y3nd Can you expand this answer to explain exactly what you did to get it working? How did you install mame? How did you use it?